# Get data from two relationed Illuminate Eloquent Model in one

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

currently in one of the project we were using direct sql queries and it is decided to remove them and implement the ORM, so we decided to use ***Illuminate Eloquent Model*** component for that. Since we are new to this, I don't have much knowledge with Relations between two Models related to each other.

current sql query

```
select * from login as A, user_profile as B where A.user_id = B.login_id and A.user_id = $user_id
```

I've created two Models, one `User` extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and another `UserProfile` extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. Model implementation is like this

**User Model**

```
<?php
namespace App\Project;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'login';

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public function profile()
    {           
        return $this->hasOne('App\Project\UserProfile', 'login_id');
    }   
}
```

**UserProfile Model**

```
<?php
namespace App\Project;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserProfile extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_profile';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function user()
    {   
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

I've a class `Manage` with a method `getUserInfo` which takes user_id as input

**Manage Class**

```
<?php
namespace App\Project;

class Manage
{
    public function getUserInfo($id)
    {
        return (new User())->profile()->where('login_id', $id)->get();      
    }
}
```

When I call this method in the application, I get **Empty Collection**

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

But If I break it in two statements like this

```
$user = User::find($id);
$profile = $user->profile()->where('login_id', $id)->get();
```

In `$user` variable I get the Object of `User` Model with data of login table and in `$profile` variable I get the Object of `UserProfile` Model with data of user_profile table. Now I'm not able to understand how can I get the result of two tables in single call using Eloquent Models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got the answer when using `where` instead of `find` am able to get single record.

```
$user = User::where('user_id', $id)->with('profile')->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
$user = User::find($id)->with('profile');
```

In the `with` clause you should put the name of your relation. This will populate the object of your relation.

Comment: This returns all the records from the table even though am finding for user_id = 1 only??

Comment: No, it will return only the records related to the user you are getting. But, of course, your model must have the relations properly set.

Comment: I've 13 records in login table, so its returning 13 records with its relation with user_profile. User will have only UserProfile to it hasOne UserProfile only and UserProfile belongs to one User only. In the above code it is mentioned. Sorry, but am not good with the relations so am not sure whether it is correctly implemented or not

Comment: In your profile table at the database the login_id field is properly set? If you perform the query it gets only the profile related to your user or everything?

Comment: Yeah, at database end, the login_id is properly set for user_profile table. when I perform this query I get the records from both the tables related to input id. `select * from login as A, user_profile as B where A.user_id = B.login_id and A.user_id = 1`

Comment: If I only use this `User::find($id);` I get single record. But using `with` returns all the records

Comment: Ok. The 'login' passed when you create your model relation is the name of foreign key in your database?
According to Laravel documentation, the second argument in hasOne method it's the foreign key name. If you wish to specify a field directly, you should use the third argument. Check this link to a more detailed explanation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: I've tried passing foreign_key `login_id` as well as local_key `user_id` as 2nd and 3rd arguments but still returns all the records. I guess somewhere am doing something wrong with relation which am not able to figure out

Answer (score 2):

There're two options:

## 1

If you want to get jointy queries result try to use DB faces like this:

```
$usersWithProfiles = \DB::table('users')
    ->distinct()
    ->join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->get();
```

This will brings you complete list of users and their profiles in each row.

## 2

If you want to use `Eloquent` you can simply access to profile like this:

```
$user->profile;
```

This will auto query the profile relation because you have defined relation method: `profile()` in user's model.

Comment: Yeah, I can do this way but then I'll have to maintain two separate variable instead of one, so am trying to achieve this by hasOne/belongsTo relationship but failing :D

Comment: I give you two ways of getting this

Comment: If you what only one var to handle everything you have to use joins. If you want to use hasOne/belongsTo then you'll have to handle two vars :)

Comment: Thanks Filip. Replacing `find` with `where` resolved the problem. But am not able to understand why `find` returns all records instead of one.